# Video is not getting closed after switching from AIR to android activity

Tags: android, sockets, service, air

This issue i am facing from the long time. So need the help for the same. The scenario is After navigating through some pages I have a button in one of the activity. On clicking on that button I have to start an AIR app. For sending data to AIR i have used socket connection in services. so clicking on that button I am starting the service as well as the AIR.In AIR app one video will be playing. but when I come back the AIR app will be closed.but the problem is after coming back from AIR the video is not getting closed. the video is still running in the background. I have closed socket connection in service also in AIR also but still the same issue. Please suggest me What can be its solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and I am posting the same for others reference. I managed flags through shared preferences and by using it that issue resolved.